# Calculating the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Let $f(x)$ be a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so it has an Oblique asymptote at $y=2x-1$. Calculate:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)f(x)$$

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-2x)=-1$, but how does it help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying by $\sin(2/x)$ and taking limits in RHS, we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\sin(2/x)f(x)-2x\sin(2/x)\right]=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(2/x)=0$$

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}2x\sin(2/x)=4$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(2/x)f(x)=4$.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Why $\lim_{x\to\infty}2x\sin(2/x)=4$? I know that  $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(1/x)=1$ but how do I take the $2$ from $\sin$?

Comment: Use l'Hopital's rule. (Or Taylor, or $o$-notation...). Also, $\sin(2/x)=2\sin(1/x)\cos(1/x)$.

Comment: I think that my professor told us that we can't use the l'Hopital's rule on this equation because we get a circuit proof. Is it true? Also why its $-4$ and not $4$?

Comment: I don't know which maths you are based on to solve the problem, but you definitely can use $\sin(2/x)=2\sin(1/x)\cos(1/x)$. Note that $\cos(1/x)\to 1$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are you sure the answer is $-4$ and not $4$? because I get $4$.

Comment: Yes, a silly mistake, it is $4$.

Comment: You can also write it as $4*(x/2)*\sin(2/x)$, if you put $t=x/2$ then you have $\lim_{t\to\infty}4* t \sin(1/t)=4*1=4$